# Google Apps Script - sendEmail With Attachments as Google Drive Links, Not Actual Files

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, mime-types

I'm trying to send an email from a Google Apps Script that would attach two files from my Drive, and attach them not as actual files, but rather links to the file in Google Drive. One of the files is a Google Doc, and the other is an MP4 in a Drive folder. Here's an example of what I mean. If I attach the MP4 as a file, it'll show up like this in Gmail:

[Screenshot of attached file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiMcw.png)

But, I'm trying to get it where it attaches just as a link, which would allow the recipient to view the video right in Gmail, like this:

[Screenshot of linked video file (note the file listed above the attachment section as well)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZzXF.png)

This would be used as part of a Google Sheet where I have a list of people with their email addresses on a sheet. Once run, this script would send an email to every person on the list, with the attachments identical for each one. Here's the code I'm currently working with:

```html
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var list = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var numRows = list.filter(String).length;
  console.log((numRows - 1) + " emails in queue.");
  for (var i = 2; i <= numRows; i += 1) {
    var name = ss.getRange(i,11).getValue();
    var first = ss.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var email = ss.getRange(i,4).getValue();
    var doc = DriveApp.getFileById('[id number]');
    var video = DriveApp.getFileById('[second id number]');
    console.log("Pre-email log for " + name);
    MailApp.sendEmail(email,'Subject','', {
      name: 'My Name',
      htmlBody: "<body>HTML content</body>",
      attachments: [doc, video]
    });
    console.log("Email sent for " + name);
  }
  console.log((numRows - 1) + " emails sent.");
}
```

Now, if I keep it like this, the email will send just fine, but the document will be formatted as a PDF, and both files will be attached as a file, not a link. My searching around has prompted me to adjust the attachments line as follows:

```
attachments: [doc.getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS), video]
```

However, when I try to test the function, it gives me this error: "Blob object must have non-null data for this operation." I've tried moving the `'.getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS)'` up to the line where the variable is defined, but it didn't work. I also checked the Doc ID and it is correct.

Also, I can't find a MIME Type that would (supposedly) work for the video file. I tried all available options I can find, including `'video/mp4'`, but nothing seems to work. For the record, the video file is ~12 MB in size.

I could simply put the sharing links to the Drive files in the body of the email, and that would accomplish what I'm trying to do, but it flags the email as a potentially dangerous message, due to being sent through the script and including the bare links. This happens if I just put the links in themselves, or if I use an `"<a href=''></a>"` tag to create a link. I've sent plenty of emails previously through an Apps Script without this issue just fine, both with and without attached files.

I feel like I'm just missing something simple, but I can't figure out how to get those two files to attach as Drive links. Is this possible? Is it possible to just embed the sharing links in the email body somehow that would allow the email to not be flagged as potentially dangerous?

I hope that makes sense; any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For anyone curious, I was able to use a workaround by using the `noReply: true` option in sending the email, and just including the links in the body (with `<a href=''></a>` to label the links. This `noReply` option is available to us since it's my work account, using G Suite. I don't think that option works for non-G Suite accounts.

This allowed the email to come through without being flagged as potentially dangerous, since it wasn't spoofing my email address. This works for my purposes, but I'd still love to find a solution where I can add the files as Drive attachments.